# How did Richard and Erlich meet?

Tags: plot-explanation, silicon-valley

I've watched seasons 1 and 2 of [Silicon Valley](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2575988/).

We know Richard is staying in Erlich's incubator as one of his *incubees*, but do we know how they originally met?

Did I miss something or is it possibly covered in a deleted scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To date no major details of how they met or how Richard came to live/work in Erlich's incubator have been divulged. The only thing we know is that Erlich gains a 10% stake in any product/company/idea people living in his incubator come up with, and just before he learned Pied Piper was viable he was planning to evict Richard from it.

**These details could come to light in future episodes, but for now they remain obscured.** However, the concept of an innovation/[business incubator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_incubator) is not new to the show, and as such is likely just a means to provide meaning for certain characters and business interactions within the show to exist, making it more believable and depicting of the actual Silicon Valley area itself.